# Which Fading Suns sourcebook details two alien cultures, one insectoid and one reptilian?

Tags: product-identification, fading-suns

I'm trying to identify a Fading Suns sourcebook I remember. One of the two species it described is insectoid and the other is reptilian. Above the back cover blurb in large print is a quote of someone warning, "Stay away from the bugs and the lizards, they're hiding something!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [*Orphaned Races: Ascorbites & Hironem*](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/56614/orphaned-races-ascorbites-hironem), published in 2003. The back cover ad copy starts with:

> “If there’s one thing I’ve learned in my years as a merc, it’s stay away from the Bugs and Lizards. They’re both hidin’ somethin’!”
>
> *Orphaned Races* examines two of the sentient races of the Fading Suns™ universe: The insectoid Ascorbites and the reptilian Hironem. […]

[image: Front cover of Orphaned Races: Ascorbites & Hironem, showing a bipedal insect person in profile wielding a glaive-like weapon, and a bipedal lizard facing the reader holding a curved sword at attention. The background is an orange-hued suggestion of vines, leaves, perhaps desert, and a low sun over alien buildings]
[image: Back cover of Orphaned Races: Ascorbites & Hironem, showing the referenced in-universe quotation]